# remove i+1th term if reoccuring

Tags: r, for-loop

Say we have the following data

```
A <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4,8,6,6,1,2,3,4)
B <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3)

data <- data.frame(A,B)
```

How would one write a function so that for `A`, if we have the same value in the `i+1th` position, then the reoccuring row is removed.

Therefore the output should like like

```
data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,8,6,1,2,3,4), c(1,2,5,1,2,3,5,1,2,3))
```

My best guess would be using a *for* statement, however I have no experience in these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
  data[c(TRUE, data[-1,1]!= data[-nrow(data), 1]),]
```

Comment: I often prefer `base` solutions to non-standard package ones (such as using `dplyr`), so I thought I'd play with this ... `dat1[c(TRUE, diff(dat1[,1]) != 0), ]`. Besides a weak *suggestion* of readability difference, this `diff` version is 25% slower ... then again, *"premature optimization is the root of all evil"*, isn't it? (Simple solution, nice.)

Comment: @r2evans yes, `diff` is slow.  I tested it several occasions and found to be not that fast compared to other solution

Comment: so the 1 in data[-nrow(data), 1] outlines the row number

Comment: @lukeg It suggests the column number i.e. `1st column`

Comment: yes, of course, how did you format 1st column in your comments? the shift+k does not work in the comment box

Answer (score 3):

Another option, `dplyr`-esque:

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,2,2,3,4,8,6,6,1,2,3,4),
                   B=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3))
dat1 %>% filter(A != lag(A, default=FALSE))
##    A B
## 1  1 1
## 2  2 2
## 3  3 5
## 4  4 1
## 5  8 2
## 6  6 3
## 7  1 5
## 8  2 1
## 9  3 2
## 10 4 3
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting another solution

Answer (score 1):

using diff, which calculates the pairwise differences with a lag of 1:

```
data[c( TRUE, diff(data[,1]) != 0), ]
```

output:

```
   A B
1  1 1
2  2 2
5  3 5
6  4 1
7  8 2
8  6 3
10 1 5
11 2 1
12 3 2
13 4 3
```

Comment: I wish I had thought of that ;-)

Comment: I saw your comment after I had already posted... and now i feeld kinda dumb, given it is written right on top of it :D, I felt rly smart when I came up with the idea, not so much anymore though :D

Comment: I'm laughing, no worries ... it's often a battle trying to get an answer/comment in before somebody else does, I've done this several times. It's a good solution that happens to be out-performed by @akrun's solution.

Comment: yeah thats the part I hate, results in quickly posting something and editing 5times... just to be faster... or worst case scenario: seeing: there is an answer while you are typing yours .... but it speaks of the activity of the community, which is very vibrant

Answer (score 0):

Using `rle`

```
A <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4,8,6,6,1,2,3,4)
B <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3)

data <- data.frame(A,B)

X <- rle(data$A)
Y <- cumsum(c(1, X$lengths[-length(X$lengths)]))
View(data[Y, ])


row.names   A   B
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
3   5   3   5
4   6   4   1
5   7   8   2
6   8   6   3
7   10  1   5
8   11  2   1
9   12  3   2
10  13  4   3
```